# What does AEDU mean?

Tags: dnd-4e, terminology

I have seen the acronym "AEDU" (or perhaps ADEU) used on the community boards at wizards.com, but haven't stumbled on the definition, and a google search goes nowhere (I doubt they're suddenly saluting in Catalan). It seems to have something to do with wizards, but what does it mean?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A: At-Will
E: Encounter
D: Daily
U: Utility

It refers to the basic structure of the powers that balances the classes and keeps the approximate effectiveness of powers between classes equal. (i.e. a 5th level daily in any class is approximately on par with a 5th level daily in any other class.)

Comment: Just an addition: a contrast would be some classes from Essentials (like the Knight, or Slayer, or Thief) who lack the traditional composition of AEDU powers seen in PHb1/2/3.

Answer (score 3):

At-Will, Encounter, Daily, Utility

Old classes had all of their powers within those types, while new Essentials classes dabble in modifying Basic Attacks.

Comment: This is incorrect in that Essentials classes non-at-will powers are still there, and that old classes still have (not "had") powers of those types. At-will Essentials powers are usually modifications of basic attacks, yes. But, corrections aside, welcome to the site!